# Strange behavior with implicits

Tags: scala, implicit

I'm using the [Scalacheck](http://code.google.com/p/scalacheck/) library to test my application. In that library there's a `Gen` object that defines implicit conversions of any object to a generator of objects of that class.

E.g., importing `Gen._` lets you call methods such as `sample` on any object, through its implicit conversion to `Gen`:

```
scala> import org.scalacheck.Gen._
import org.scalacheck.Gen._

scala> "foo" sample
res1: Option[java.lang.String] = Some(foo)
```

In this example, the implicit `Gen.value()` is applied to `"foo"`, yielding a generator that always returns `Some(foo)`.

But this doesn't work:

```
scala> import org.scalacheck.Gen.value
import org.scalacheck.Gen.value

scala> "foo" sample                   
<console>:5: error: value sample is not a member of java.lang.String
       "foo" sample
             ^
```

Why not?

**Update**

I'm using Scala 2.7.7final and ScalaCheck 2.7.7-1.6.

**Update**

Just switched to Scala 2.8.0.final with ScalaCheck 2.8.0-1.7. The problem did indeed go away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried this with Scala 2.8.0.final and ScalaCheck 1.7 built for the same. Both imports worked, meaning the second line produced the desired result for both imports:

```
scala> "foo" sample
res1: Option[java.lang.String] = Some(foo)
```

What version of Scala and ScalaCheck did you use?

Comment: I'm using Scala 2.7.7final and ScalaCheck 2.7.7-1.6. Is this a bug in those versions? Should I upgrade?

Comment: It might be 2.7.7 limitation, but upgrading to 2.8 is a big step, so do that only when you're ready.

Comment: @lindelof: 2.7 is a dead end and is not being maintained. I strongly advise upgrading to 2.8 ASAP. It is not as big a task as you might think.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: You did not import the implicit conversion (whatever its name is), you only imported something called `value` from object `org.scalacheck.Gen`.

Correction / clarification:

`Gen.value` (that's `object Gen`, not `trait Gen[+T]`) is the implicit used to wrap arbitrary values in an instance of (an anonymous class implementing) `trait Gen[T]` (where `T` is a function from `Gen.Params` to the argument to which `Gen.value` is applied). `Gen.sample` is a method of `trait Gen[T]` that invokes its (the concrete `Gen` subclass) `apply` method to get the synthesized value.

Sadly, having looked closer, I have to admit I don't understand why the code doesn't work when the rest of the members of `object Gen` are not imported.